# Restrict module function visibility in a project with library, binary and a module file

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a project with three files:

1. Module file (`src/foo.rs`)
2. Library file (`src/lib.rs`)
3. Binary file (`src/main.rs`)

I want to have public functions in the module file with visibility restricted to the library and binary files only.

I have tried using `pub(crate)`, `pub(super)`, and the like but to no avail.

I want to design the project structure in a way so that:

1. Only `pub` functions in `lib.rs` can be called from outside while using it as a dependency crate.
2. All the functions in `foo.rs` should be visible only to `lib.rs` and `main.rs`.
3. All the functions in `main.rs` should be private.

EDIT1: I want it because `pub(crate)` warns me of dead code while `pub` doesn't. I don't want any dead code inside the module. In the maintenance of large projects, it helps out quite a bit with debugging and refactoring.

EDIT2: [Rust Internals Thread](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/restrict-module-function-visibility-in-a-project-with-library-binary-and-a-module-file/15801)

Comment: Does `main.rs` rely on `lib.rs` as a dependency and do you want `main.rs` access `foo.rs` through `lib.rs`?

Comment: @kmdreko that the same thing no ?

Comment: your question don't make any sense, xy problem ? I suggest you forget that idea. At the very least you should explain WHY you want that.

Comment: *Only pub functions in lib.rs* — that's how Rust works naturally; nothing special is needed. *All the functions in main.rs* — it doesn't really matter if they are private or not as you can't use a binary as a dependency in the first place. *All the functions in foo.rs* — what makes _your_ main.rs different from any other crate that might use the library? Nothing in Rust has the concept of a "friend" crate that you trust.

Comment: @Stargatuer I was mostly asking in case both `lib.rs` and `main.rs` were *both* declaring the `foo` module separately.

Comment: And, for those following along, if *both* `lib.rs` and `main.rs` said `mod foo`, that's 99.95% of the time a Very Bad Idea.

Comment: @Stargateur check my updated post

Comment: Your edits don't really add more context I'm afraid; `pub` in `foo.rs` shouldn't silence dead code warnings unless `foo` is also public outside the crate. Could you perhaps make a simplified example of how you're using these files?

Comment: @kmdreko You are right, I just checked. Closing this question, my understanding is now clear.

Answer (score 0):

1. That is what `pub` does.
2. you need to use `pub(crate)` for those functions in foo.rs.
3. As main.rs is a binary file it cannot be imported so they are all essentially private.